# how to create new partition using Gparted inside elementary os?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, files

1.while I was installing os it asks for erasing all the data on HDDs so it also deletes all the partitions on HDDs so now I want to create a 2 new partition on HDDs how to do that????

2. Shortcut key for the option of the shutdown like we have in win10 alt+f4 and the option comes to the shutdown, restart, and other options...
3. The steam app which I install from the app center is not working working what to do....?

Comment: When you ask a question and you receive answers into StackExchange they are not only for you but for everyone who has the same question later to be able to view the answers instead of asking the same again and again and again. For this reason it will be better when you have 3 questions to ask them into 3 different topics, because for example I can give you an answer now for one of your questions, but you cannot accept it because you have 2 more. So if you want to participate into the community properly I recommend you to divide your list into 3 different questions.

Comment: Thank u I appreciate your advice, next time I will remember those things...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a USB key with Elementary Os and boot on this key.

Choose "try", then using Gparted, it is then very simple to shrink the partition which contains Elementary on the hard drive of the PC, then to create a new partition with the amount of available space.

Have a nice week end !

Jean-Louis / France.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have free space on your disk
 - boot to a live distro that has graphical gparted tool in it
 - resize your / partition down to whatever you are comfortable with
 - boot back to your running OS on the hard disk to verify disk okay
 - with the free disk space create another partition
 - create a filesystem (maybe ext4) for this partition
 - create a mount point for this new filesystem
 - mount it manually to test it out
 - add new partition to /etc/fstab

Damn ... why isn't this post formatting correctly